# Assign class to Drop Down Selections in WooCommerce Products Custom Fields

Tags: custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

I have added a drop down to the WooCommerce Inventory Tab where the user can choose message to show in front end.

In functions.php:

```
// Display Fields in Back End
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_status_fields' );

function woo_add_custom_status_fields() {

global $woocommerce, $post;
// Add Select to WooCommerce Inventory Tab in Back End
woocommerce_wp_select( 
    array( 
        'id'      => 'productstatus_select',
        'label'   => __( 'Product Status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'options' => array(
            'Message one'   => __( 'The message', 'woocommerce' ),
            'Message two'   => __( 'The message', 'woocommerce' ),
            'Message three'   => __( 'The message', 'woocommerce' ),
            )
        )
    );
}

// Save Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_status_fields_save' );

function woo_add_custom_status_fields_save( $post_id ){
    $woocommerce_select = $_POST['productstatus_select'];
        if( !empty( $woocommerce_select ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'productstatus_select', esc_attr( $woocommerce_select ) );
}
```

The selected value is retrieved with following code in woocommerce/single-product/meta.php

```
    <?php
    // Display Custom Field Value in Front End
    echo '<p class="productstatus">' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'productstatus_select', true ) .'</p>';
    ?>
```

Now I’m wondering if there is any possibility to assign separate classes to the different selections so I can style the outputted code. For example make Message One red, Message Two green, etc in front end. I’m not sure if the options should be arrays or if I need an additional function to achieve that. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: asking for opinion is not really a question ;) asking about coding style is pointless over here, if it works for you that is great, usually there is very little interest in the theoretical differences between two coding styles, unless you specifically ask about that.

Comment: Thanks @Mark for your reply. Maybe you misinterpreted my question. I'm not asking for an opinion but a solution.

Comment: asking for suggestions === asking for opinions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in the following way!

1. Create an array of CSS class names and message values

   ```
   $colors_stings = array(
       'Message one' => 'message_color_green',
       'Message two'   => 'message_color_red',
       'Message three' => 'message_color_blue'
   );
   ```
2. Check if message string exist in array then assign CSS color class to variable.

   ```
   $css_class = isset($colors_stings[$product_status]) ? $colors_stings[$product_status] : 'message_default_color';
   ```

Complete Example:-

```
$colors_stings = array(
    'Message one' => 'message_color_green',
    'Message two'   => 'message_color_red',
    'Message three' => 'message_color_blue'
);

$product_status = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'productstatus_select', true );
$css_class = isset($colors_stings[$product_status]) ? $colors_stings[$product_status] : 'message_default_color';

echo '<p class="productstatus '. $css_class . '">' . $product_status .'</p>';
```

Comment: Ah, I had something like this in mind but didn’t know how to do it. Thank you. Just a question though, where in my function do i add the forst part with $color_strings?

Comment: Ok, just realized that all of it should go into meta.php. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

As the keys already hold PHP generated output, it *should* be possible to simply wrap them in some MarkUp

```
woocommerce_wp_select( 
    array( 
        'id'      => 'productstatus_select',
        'label'   => __( 'Product Status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'options' => array(
            'Message one'   => sprintf( 
                '<span class="message--important">%s</span>', 
                __( 'The message', 'woocommerce' ) 
            ),
            'Message two'   => '<span class="foo__bar">'.__( 'The message', 'woocommerce' ).'</span>',
            'Message three' => '<em>'.__( 'The message', 'woocommerce' ).'</em>',
            )
        )
    );
}
```

In case you need different MarkUp on multiple different admin pages, you will want to check against `get_current_screen()` properties and switch the MarkUp accordingly. I would only suggest doing so in case you do not want to have the MarkUp directly in your applications business logic/implementation, but inject the output from above somehow (e.g. via a filter).

Comment: Cool, I did not think about it!

Comment: @Sumit To be honest, your answer is more flexible. In case you need different markup in different admin pages, you would need to check `get_current_screen()` properties in my answer. That would make it harder, hence the upvote to your answer.

Comment: Yes make sense to me.

Comment: @kaiser Hmm couldn’t get this to work actually. It just prints the message, not the span. Unless I need to change something in meta.php?

Comment: @MadLandley I added three variants … please update your question with what you tried and what the output is, then ping me here again.

Comment: @kaiser I tried all three of them but none worked. Went with the solution from Summit which worked and marked his answer as accepted. Sorry for sounding like a noob here but isn't that the way to do it? :)

Comment: @MadLandley Have you actually looked into the source code (using dev tools or firebug or similar) on what you actually get?